# Generating random numbers unique from another variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've generated an array of three random numbers unique from each other (no duplicates). Now I also want to make sure that all three of the random numbers are also unique from the variable "answer".

```
var answer = 4;

//Generating the three random numbers
var arr = [];

while (arr.length < 3) {
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    if (arr.indexOf(random_number) == -1) { 
        arr.push( random_number );
    }
}
```

I cant seem to make it so that each of the three numbers is not equal to the variable 'answer'

Comment: Some programming advice: use [`if(arr.includes(random_number)) {`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of using [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and comparing it to `-1`. And [use `let` instead of `var`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274342/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-var-keyword-in-es6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition to your `if` statement:

```
if (arr.indexOf(random_number) == -1 && random_number != answer) {
  arr.push(random_number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't try that. I did try "||" though lol

Answer (score 0):

add && condition also

```
var answer = 4;

//Generating the three random numbers
var arr = [];

while (arr.length < 3) {
    var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    if (arr.indexOf(random_number) == -1 && random_number != answer) { 
        arr.push( random_number );
    }
}
```